# Google chrome opening on start up without being ever installed

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, win10-fast-startup

my pc has always worked really well but lately it has been slowing down a little. Now whenever I turn on the PC it opens google chrome, but google chrome has never even been on this PC. Please, I use my PC to make music and it is my life, what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome was likely installed as an opt-in for some other software, but does not explain why it launches on startup.

In any case, you should be able to uninstall it from 'Apps & features'.

Here is more information, if you want to keep Chrome installed, but stop it from launching on starup:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/chrome-opens-automatically-after-startrebooting-on/f1c1973f-d7d1-4267-a5ee-d20ddc49d0f1?auth=1

Comment: When I type google Chrome in the "Type here to search bar" right beside the windows icon Google Chrome does not show up.

Comment: is there a way to upload photos?

Comment: Hey I don't want to keep chrome installed but it is not showing up in my programs, what can I do?

Comment: In order for Chrome to launch, on Win 10 it should show up in: 'Apps & features' (which is what you searched, correct?).